# Rails filing system's don't match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, filesystems, bitbucket

When I built my Rails environment my file system in my IDE and on Bitbucket got mitched-matched. How should I fix it?
[image: BitBucket filing system]

[image: IDE filing system]

[image: removed the -/tmp from the .gitignore file]

[image: console after doing a git push]
[image: File system still hasn't changed. I've tried what was suggested from the both root and subfolders]
[image: No change to filing system]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try doing a `git pull ...` as suggested by the error/hint message in your screenshot.

If that fails, then try `git pull --rebase` to rebase your code onto the HEAD

Also, try `git push -f`.

Note: A forced push overwrites the structure and sequence of commits on the authoritative repository, throwing away other people's commits. `git push -f` should be avoided.

Comment: please don't tell someone who is clearly new to programming to `git push -f` without explaining why it's happening and what it does

Comment: You're right. I answered on my mobile device while on the go. I elaborated on my answer adding a note on using `git push -f` and adding an alternative solution (`git pull --rebase`).